# bessern vs verbessern

Tags: meaning, verb, meaning-in-context, prefix

What's the difference between **bessern** and **verbessern**?

Is the earlier used mainly for health improvements (judging by the expression *Gute Besserung!*) and the latter for skill improvements (judging by *Ich muss viel verbessern*)?

Comment: it's pretty much the same, check: https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=auto&tl=en&text=bessern

Answer (score 1):

*bessern* is chiefly abstract, about character of people and perhaps abstract Ideas.

> Der Schüler muss sich **bessern**.

*verbessern* is about discrete qualities of things, generally so if the root is an adjective (cp "vergolden", "verletzen").

> Die Situation, die Schulnote, die Gesundheit müssen sich bessern. Ich muss meine Noten **verbessern**.

The difference is not strict, because *ver-* is also used with verbs, and it might appear as if *verbessern* derives from *bessern*, so *verbessern* may be used in place of bessern. On the other hand, *verbessern* might appear like a reduction from *verbessern*, or a verbalization of Proto-Germanic *bataz "good", so they are used somewhat interchangeably. But if you act on something, it's strictly *verbessern*. That's the only difference I see.

Answer (score 1):

You can see `bessern` as the base form of `verbessern`. The prefix `ver-` adds a specification to the verb.
In this case it denotes that an action of a subject is taken to make something better, instead of it just *happening*.

In current language, `bessern` is rarely used outside of idioms (such as `Gute Besserung`) and `verbessern` is used as a replacement in spoken language, although in my opinion the exact meaning of it got a bit lost.

Answer (score 0):

The verb *bessern* is seldom used because it's about the lack of character of someone.

> Er muss sich bessern.

That's something a person of authority would say about a delinquent.

> Er hat sich gebessert.

That's what his defense attorney would say to the judge.

A century ago, people still said

> Mein Zustand hat sich sehr gebessert.

to say their health condition got better. But nowadays that's

> Mein Zustand hat sich sehr verbessert.

and

> Gute Besserung!

is a fixed expression as a vestige of that old-tyme language.

---

In almost all other cases, *verbessern* is used.

Comment: ich will Dich nicht "ausbessern" aber ich denke "Mein Zustand hat sich sehr gebessert" wird auch in unserem Jahrhundert nach wie vor verwendet :)